# In Python, how can I get a line number corresponding to a given character location?

Tags: python

If I have a text that I've read into memory by using `open('myfile.txt').read()`, and if I know a certain location in this file, say, at character 10524, how can I find the line number of that location?

Comment: Count the number of newlines (`\n`) before the character.

Comment: I'm guessing you already knew the solution of counting the newline characters up to that point, and asked this question hoping for an answer that beats O(n). No such answer exists.

Comment: @SarcasticSully That's true, but there would still be a huge performance difference between doing it manually in Python, or having it done by a function implemented in C in the standard library. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
txt = open('myfile.txt').read()
lineno = len([c for c in txt[:10524] if c == '\n'])
```

Comment: This solution builds up a list of all line breaks in the string, then counts that list. This is quite a lot of unnecessary work, and if the string is very long (for example a log file) then this would probably be quite slow and consume a lot of memory. If performance is a priority, using `str.count()` should probably be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the text preceding your desired position and count the number of `\n` characters.

Comment: Are there any standard library functions that can do this faster than manually looping through each character in the string and counting the occurrences of `\n`?

Comment: @Hubro No, I don't think so.  You'll have to manually loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best performing solution would be:

```py
char_position = 10524

lineno = 1 + txt.count("\n", 0, char_position)
```

This uses the the built-in `str.count()` method, which presumably is implemented in C and should perform vastly better than counting manually.

The second and third argument limits the counting to a slice of the string. By passing `0` and `10524`, you are saying "count all line breaks up until character 10524". The result is the 0-based line index of the character position. Since you presumably want a 1-based line number, just add 1.